# Problems to calculate the angle of the arrows to simulate a magnetic field

Tags: javascript, math, physics

Im programming a magnetic field simulator with a max of 4 charges but i dont understand what is wrong with the angle calculation.

function generarCargas is the function that creates the arrows, sorry if i didnt comment, if you have any questions with the code i will answer immediately.

JS:

```
//Funcion angle
function angle(cx, cy, ex, ey) {
    const dy = ey - cy;
    const dx = ex - cx;
    const rad = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    const deg = (rad * 180) / Math.PI;
    return deg;
}

//Funcion getPositionAtCenter
function getPositionAtCenter(element) {
    const { top, left, width, height } = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: left + width / 2,
        y: top + height / 2,
    };
}

//Funcion getDistanceBetweenElements
function getDistanceBetweenElements(a, b) {
    const aPosition = getPositionAtCenter(a);
    const bPosition = getPositionAtCenter(b);

    return Math.hypot(aPosition.x - bPosition.x, aPosition.y - bPosition.y);
}



function generarCargas(selectValues) {
    const arrows = document.querySelectorAll(".arrow");

    selectValues.forEach((carga) => {
        const cargaDiv = document.createElement("div");
        cargaDiv.className = "carga";
        const div = document.createElement("div");
        cargaDiv.appendChild(div);
        div.textContent = carga;
        allCampo.appendChild(cargaDiv);
        valoresCarga = carga;
    });

    let dragItem = null;
    let offsetX = 0;
    let offsetY = 0;

    allCampo.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
        const cargaDiv = e.target.closest(".carga");

        if (cargaDiv) {
            dragItem = cargaDiv;
            offsetX = e.clientX - cargaDiv.getBoundingClientRect().left;
            offsetY = e.clientY - cargaDiv.getBoundingClientRect().top;

            document.addEventListener("mousemove", handleDrag);
            document.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
                document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleDrag);
                dragItem = null;
            });

            function handleDrag(e) {
                if (dragItem) {
                    const posX = e.clientX - offsetX;
                    const posY = e.clientY - offsetY;
                    dragItem.style.left = posX + "px";
                    dragItem.style.top = posY + "px";
                }
                const cargas = document.querySelectorAll(".carga");

                arrows.forEach((arrow) => {
                    let angles = [];

                    let eRx = 0;
                    let eRy = 0;
                    let resultantAngle;

                    cargas.forEach((carga, index) => {
                        let qx = getPositionAtCenter(carga).x;
                        let qy = getPositionAtCenter(carga).y;
                        let distancia = getDistanceBetweenElements(arrow, carga) / 100;
                        let e;

                        const rekt = arrow.getBoundingClientRect();
                        const anchorX = rekt.left + rekt.width / 2;
                        const anchorY = rekt.top + rekt.height / 2;
                        let angleDeg = angle(qx, qy, anchorX, anchorY);

                        let cargaValue = parseInt(carga.textContent);

                        if (cargaValue < 0) {
                            angleDeg = angleDeg - 180;
                            cargaValue = -cargaValue;
                        }

                        e = (k * cargaValue) / Math.pow(distancia, 2);

                        let ex = e * Math.cos((angleDeg * Math.PI) / 180);
                        let ey = e * Math.sin((angleDeg * Math.PI) / 180);

                        eRx += ex;
                        eRy += ey;

                        angles.push(angleDeg);
                    });

                    let resultant = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(eRx, 2) + Math.pow(eRy, 2));

                    let tanAlpha = eRy / eRx;
                    let alpha = (Math.atan(tanAlpha) * 180) / Math.PI;

                    arrow.style.transform = "rotate(" + alpha + "deg)";
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Image of the resultant arrows:
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3I3hK.jpg)